# Importing module in Python doesn't work(Graphlab)

Tags: python, graphlab

I am trying to use graphlab.evaluation.log_loss [function](https://dato.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.evaluation.log_loss.html) though I can't import it.
I try to use log_loss function :

```
evaluation.log_loss(..)
```

but I get the following error: "
**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'log_loss'"**
though other metrics such as confusion_matrix, rmse and others are working. Any ideas?

Comment: What OS and graphlab version are you using? On a side note, I think the more pythonic pattern would be `from graphlab import evaluation`.

Comment: @papayawarrior you are about "from graphlab import evalution". Version : '1.6.1'. OS : Mac OS X El Capitan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `log_loss` evaluation function was added in GraphLab Create version 1.7, so upgrading should do the trick.

```
>>> import graphlab
>>> graphlab.version
'1.7.1'

>>> from graphlab import evaluation
>>> evaluation.log_loss(graphlab.SArray([1, 0, 1]), 
                        graphlab.SArray([0.7, 0.4, 0.8]))
0.3635480396729776
```